# QSystemTrayIcon without context menu in Qt5 possible?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, contextmenu, qsystemtrayicon

I am using `QSystemTrayIcon` for the first time, and it was trivial to implement. My code looks like this:

```
if(!connect(mTrayIcon, &QSystemTrayIcon::activated, this, &MiniStudio::onTrayActivated)) {
    qWarning()<<"ERROR: could not connect QSystemTrayIcon";
}

mTrayIcon->setIcon(QIcon(":/icons/record.svg"));
mTrayIcon->setToolTip("Show MiniStudio controls");
mTrayIcon->setContextMenu(nullptr);
mTrayIcon->show();
```

As you probably understand from my code I ***don't*** want to display a context menu, I simply want a button in the tray that when clicked shows my application window.

The code sort of works, however, even if I specify a "nullptr" context menu, there still is a strange-looking box appearing under my tray icon whenever I click it, as if there is a context menu without any items in it (please see screenshot below).

[image: Strange looking box under QSystemTrayIcon]

So my questions are:

- Am I doing something wrong?
- How can I make the strange box go away?
- Is this a bug, or maybe a feature of Qt on my platform?

*PS: I am developing this code for **Ubuntu 16.04 amd64** but I think the answer to this question should be relevant to any platform.*

**NOTE: I have also tried just omitting the setContextMenu() call instead of calling it with `nullptr`, and that didn't work either. The result was exactly the same.**

Any input welcome,

Thank you!

Comment: i opened "System Tray Icon Example" from Qt examples, and commented the line "trayIcon->setContextMenu(trayIconMenu);" out from "createTrayIcon" function, it looks like it works on Windows 10. did you try it out?

Comment: I don't have access to Windows, sorry. I am guessing this is a bug in Qt!

Comment: I think what @sddk means is comment out the `setContextMenu` instead of setting it to `nullptr` and test it on your ubuntu machine. also it might not be a bug in Qt but maybe your window manager or whatever (Gnome?), who knows.

Comment: Ah. That is what i tried first. I should have mentioned it.